# How to properly nest rows in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

TB uses a 12 column grid system. When one is nesting a row within a, say, `span8` like this:

```
<div class="span8">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <!-- what's the total of the span* here? -->
   </div>
</div>
```

What should the total of the span* be in the nested row? Should it be 8 because the container is 8? Or should it be 12 because TB uses 12 column grid (meaning it makes 12 column grid inside every `row` and `row-fluid` regardless of the container)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a normal `.row` you should not exceed the `span` of the wrapper, or the block will overflow.

If you use a `.row-fluid` you should always add up to 12 to occupy the entire parent.

Something like this:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='span8'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='span8'>do not exceed span of parent (8)</div>
        </div>
        <br/>
       <div class='row-fluid'>
            <div class='span12'>always go to 12!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2VF6B/

Answer (score 1):

It's different for fluid or fixed layout.

If you use `span8` in fixed layout then it's always same width - `770px`. Nested rows should have at most 8 columns, so let's say `span6+span2` or `span4+span4`.

Fluid layout - `span8`, then it always will be `66,66%` width of the browser. Nested rows will count width of this `span8` as `100%`, so you can use nested `span12` or `span6+span6`.

I hope it's clear.